# Can .NET MAUI have a transparent overlay that ignores events but has a child button which accepts events?

Tags: maui

We have an overlay on top of our active content which contains a button. We would like the button to be active while events occurring in the rest of the overlay are passed to the active content behind.

The hierarchy looks like

```
[App]
  [Window]
    [NavigationPage]
      [OurPage]
        [Grid]
          ActiveContent[StackLayout]
            [ContentView]
          Overlay[ContentView]
            [Grid]
              OverlayButton[ImageButton]
```

We have tried toggling the InputTransparent property on the overlay, however, that means the overlay button within the overlay doesn't receive events. iOS has some hit test methods for views as well as methods for gesture recognizers that would allow this to work. Is there anything similar in .NET MAUI?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Is there anything similar in .NET MAUI?

On maui, you can try to add `TapGestureRecognizer` to the overlay ContentView .

```
    <!--the overlay  -->
    <ContentView 
             Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
             Grid.RowSpan="3"
             BackgroundColor="Transparent"
             HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
             VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <ContentView.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped ="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped" NumberOfTapsRequired="1"
            />
        </ContentView.GestureRecognizers>

        <Button  Clicked="Button_Clicked"
                HeightRequest="60"  WidthRequest="100" />
    </ContentView>
```

I created a demo and achieved the similar function, you can refer to the following code:

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiTapApp411.MainPage">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="100" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <BoxView Color="Green" />
        <Label Text="Row 0, Column 0"
               HorizontalOptions="Center"
               VerticalOptions="Center" />
        <BoxView Grid.Column="1"
                 Color="Blue" />
        <Label Grid.Column="1"
               Text="Row 0, Column 1"
               HorizontalOptions="Center"
               VerticalOptions="Center" />

        <BoxView Grid.Row="1"
                 Color="Teal" />
        <Label Grid.Row="1"
               Text="Row 1, Column 0"
               HorizontalOptions="Center"
               VerticalOptions="Center" />

        <BoxView Grid.Row="1"
                 Grid.Column="1"
                 Color="Purple" />
        <Button Grid.Row="1"
               Grid.Column="1"
               Text="Row1, Column 1"
               HorizontalOptions="Center"
               VerticalOptions="Center" />

        <!--the overlay  -->
        <ContentView 
                 Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                 Grid.RowSpan="3"
                 BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                 HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                 VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <ContentView.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped ="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped" NumberOfTapsRequired="1"
                />
            </ContentView.GestureRecognizers>

            <Button  Clicked="Button_Clicked"
                    HeightRequest="60"  WidthRequest="100" />
        </ContentView>

    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage 
{
      int count = 0;

      public MainPage()
      {
            InitializeComponent();
      }

    private  void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        doSomething();
    }

    private void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, TappedEventArgs e)
    {
        doSomething();
    }
    private async void doSomething() {
        await DisplayAlert("Alert", "You have been alerted", "OK");
    }
}
```

**Note:**

From above code, you can try to listen to the tap event of the overlay contentview(e.g. `TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped`), and add the necessary code to the  function `TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped` which is the same to the code added to the click event of the inner button.

```
private  void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        doSomething();
    }

    private void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, TappedEventArgs e)
    {
        doSomething();
    }
    private async void doSomething() {
        await DisplayAlert("Alert", "You have been alerted", "OK");
    }
```

Comment: @jessie-zhang-msft Is there a way to have the Button receive clicks but also have the ContentView ignore clicks so users can interact with elements behind it? In my case, the ContentView is transparent and on top of other content.

Comment: Even if the `ContentView` is transparent, it is still overlaid on other Views, and you can only listen to the controls on the `ContentView`, not the underlying controls. But you can reduce the size of this `ContentView` to achieve the effect you say. In this condition, you can listen to the event of the underlying controls.

Comment: @jessie-zhang-msft I appreciate the followup. Our solution will be to reduce the size of the ContentView. Thank you.

Comment: Except that Microsoft has deprecated the `...AndExpand` layout options.